# Black space between cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A table view is embedded in a view controller, and a black space appears between two cells. I tried to adjust cell height in `heightForRow:atIndexPath' method, but nothing happens. The space is first visible between the two first cells, and after the cell disappeared and re-appeared, it's visible between the second and third cell.

[image: Between the blue and the white cell]

[image: Between the two first cells]

Does anyone got a solution to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the question a little is not clear. but by any chance, I guess your problem will be fixed by setting 'Cell Seperator' of your table view to 'None'. Did you try it?

Comment: That's not it, but actually that was the search bar border which is black by default. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you solved your problem, post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so this can help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

That was the search bar border. Just set its tint color to clear color to remove this black border.